# Configuring quartz failover with spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a problem in implementing failover with the configuration in the subject. I have a spring batch job configured in a quartz (2.1.7) cluster. In configuration file, I have set `requestsRecovery = true`, and my quartz configuration file is this:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = quartzScheduler 
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false 
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false 
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true 

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true 
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true 

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRPC_ 

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate 
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true 
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

My spring configuration is as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.myproject.scheduler" /> 

<bean name="myJob" class="it.myproject.scheduler.CustomJobDetailFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jobClass" value="it.myproject.scheduler.SellJob" /> 
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" /> 
    <property name="durability" value="true"/> 
</bean> 

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="it.myproject.scheduler.CustomCronTriggerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob"/> 
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${sched.expression}"/> 
</bean> 

<bean id="quartzScheduler" 
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetails"> 
        <list> 
            <ref bean="myJob" /> 
        </list> 
    </property> 
    <property name="triggers"> 
        <list> 
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" /> 
        </list> 
    </property> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" /> 
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> 
    <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler"/> 
    <property name="configLocation" value="file:///quartz.properties" /> 
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" /> 
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/> 
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" /> 
    <property name="jobFactory"> 
        <bean class="it.myproject.scheduler.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory"/> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Job code:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean; 
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailAwareTrigger; 

public class CustomCronTriggerFactoryBean extends CronTriggerFactoryBean { 

    @Override 
    public void afterPropertiesSet() { 
        super.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        // Remove the JobDetail element 
        getJobDataMap().remove(JobDetailAwareTrigger.JOB_DETAIL_KEY); 
    } 
} 

public class CustomJobDetailFactoryBean extends JobDetailFactoryBean { 
    private boolean requestsRecovery; 

    public CustomJobDetailFactoryBean() { 
        super(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void afterPropertiesSet() { 
        super.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = (JobDetailImpl) getObject(); 
        jobDetail.setRequestsRecovery(isRequestsRecovery()); 
    } 

    public boolean isRequestsRecovery() { 
        return requestsRecovery; 
    } 

    public void setRequestsRecovery(boolean requestsRecovery) { 
        this.requestsRecovery = requestsRecovery; 
    } 
} 

public class myJob extends QuartzJobBean {
    @Autowired 
    private MyScheduler task; 

    @Override 
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException { 
        task.runJob(); 
    } 
}
```

I have deployed my application in 2 separate machines on tomcat. Concurrency works fine, when I start the servers only 1 instance acquire the lock and works, but if I stop the machine that has acquired the lock, the second machine does not failover. The same result is observed if I use only one server, stopping this and restarting does not failover. 
In the table `job detail` the column `requests_recovery` is set to 1. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. What I am doing is, wiping out the tables when the instance starts. Especially, the tables that have auto-generated Instance ID. But there must be other solution for this.